# How to limit the number of "candidate" documents when using the "fq" parameter in SOLR

Tags: java, solr

I believe this will require custom coding, but what I'd like to do is

a) require that queries run against solr contain a value for the filter query parameter (fq)

b) short circuit the request if the resulting candidate list from the filter query is larger than some threshold.

From looking at the SOLR code is seems like I can do the first by providing a custom component to the /select request handler (via the config file), but the second is a little bit more murky.

Is anyone aware of a plugin already implementing something like this?  Or has suggestions on how to implement it?  As best I can see if I extend QueryComponent and inject a custom SolrIndexSearcher it ought to be possible, but I'm not seeing where the filter cache is used exactly (get from cache I found).

*edit, adding a sample query*

Here's an example query, after sanitizing it

https://....?q=startDate%3A%5B2019-01-10T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%20TO%202019-01-10T23%3A59%3A59.999Z%5D%20AND%20(name%3A%22grr%22)&wt=json&sort=startDate%20asc&fl=recordId,startDate,aName,aSomethingOrOtherType,&start=0&rows=50&joinCollection=

The application is multi-tenant, and while some tenants produce a smaller volume of documents others produce very larger volumes.  We already force a date range into the search to limit the total number of potential documents looked at, but what we'd really like is be able to determine the total number of potential documents before considering anything else and fail the request if it's too broad.  That way we don't incur the cost of the additional search parameters or sorting.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what are you trying to do with a sample query ?

Comment: .. and do you only require the `fq` to be present, or do you have a default value you could provide if it's not given? (i.e. could you use the standard default-value-for-parameter support in `solrconfig.xml`?) What is your motivation for short circuiting the request for a large set of documents? Are you using an expensive ranking for those documents?

Comment: I added a sample query and probably what's a re-iteration of what I said before.  It might be a little more clearly defined now however.  There won't be a default value however, we want the request to fail if there's no fq.

Comment: "what we'd really like is be able to determine the total number of potential documents" .. which is what the search actually does - it's hard to determine the total number of potential documents before actually performing the search to determine the documents included in the search. From your use cases I think this might be easier to implement in a middleware (that acts as a proxy between your users and Solr) instead of inside Solr.

Comment: @MatsLindh we have a middle ware already.  But in order to implement this from the middle ware I'd have to run two queries against SOLR.  The first would be a count using the filter query, then assuming it's a small enough candidate set, run the full query with both the filter and the "query" query.  That's two round trips, and would increase the load on what is already a fairly heavily loaded replicated set of SOLR servers.

Comment: Usually you'd solve these issues with a re-rank query, where the re-ranking (the expensive part of the query) only happens for a subset of documents - i.e. only the top 1000 or similar.